# PHP Como gerar um ID único igual o do encurtador do GOOGLE

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web

goo.gl/A4hI
 Como posso estar gerando um ID igual esse do google e verificar se ele já existe, caso exita gere outro. PHP

Comment: Pode postar mais algumas informações por favor. Que tipo de ID você quer gerar? Quantos caracteres? Só números? Como você pretende guardar esse ID?

Comment: Cada vez que insiro um dado no banco de dados ele retorna o ID gerado por exemplo 5, então pra acessar esse dado fica site.com/5 , mas eu queria que ficasse igual ao do google por exemplo site.com/Hi4jx . Mas na hora de gerar tem que verificar se os caracteres gerados já não existem. Tem que ter no maximo 5 caracteres e tem que ser Case Sensitive

Comment: Basta usar o ID normal da tabela (autoincremento) e converter em base 64. Se quiser otimizar mais ainda, use uma base maior que 64, desde que respeite caracteres válidos em URLs. Ou seja, você não gera o ID, ele já existe. Quase todo encurtador faz isso, inclusive a grande maioria é sequencial, pois a previsibilidade do ID é irrelevante quando não se sabe o que vai ser o conteúdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confesso que não sei uma forma de fazer isso automaticamente. Mas uma solução que eu pensei foi você fazer uma tabela associativa entre um ID e os caracteres gerados. Você faria uma função que geraria esses 5 caracteres, conferia se esses caracteres já estão sendo usados, caso contrário salve o ID e o código no banco de dados.

Caso queira uma função para gerar esses caracteres estou deixando um exemplo aqui

```
function gerarCaracteres($tamanho = 5) {
    $caracteres = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $retorno = '';
    $len = strlen($caracteres);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $tamanho; $i++) {
        $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
        $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
    }
    return $retorno;
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso cara, vlw

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas coisas para se considerar:

1. **É interessante que esconda o número?**

   Se você tem `/1`, `/2`, `/3` um usuário pode alterar a valor e obter valores anteriores. Isso é muito ruim em alguns casos, por exemplo no YouTube. O YouTube permite vídeos ocultos. Se eles fossem sequenciais um usuário teria alta probabilidade de achar esses vídeos. Além de problemas de sincronização entre os servidores.

   *Mas, isso não é preciso em todos os casos.*
2. **É interessante usar letras?**

   Você pode gerar um número aleatório, apenas, sem converter para letras e símbolos. O uso de letras e símbolos é utilizado porque o URL é tratado como texto.

   Tipicamente, você é capaz de gerar de <sub>0</sub> até <sub>18.446.744.073.709.551.615</sub>, usando apenas 8 bytes, *UINT64*. Entretanto, se você tiver um URL de `/18446744073709551614`, você irá utilizar 20 bytes, justamente porque cada número será tratado como uma letra qualquer, um byte individual.

   Somando isso, bancos de dados também iriam tratar cada letra um byte (*supondo que use base64*), sendo pior para encontrar os dados e ocupando maior espaço em disco. Por isso, utilizar números seria a melhor opção.

---

Minha sugestão:

1. Crie um valor aleatório e não-previsível (para o atacante).
2. Codifique para base64 afim de "compacta-lo", para o URL.
3. Quando o cliente acessar o link, decodifique o base64 para o valor número.
4. Procure no banco de dados pelo valor numérico.

---

Para criar o URL utilize:

```
$int = random_int(PHP_INT_MIN, PHP_INT_MAX);

$base64 = base64_encode(pack('J*', $int)); 
$base64 = rtrim(strtr($base64, '+/', '-_'), '=');
```

Este código foi [baseado nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266208/como-passar-int-para-base-64-em-php). Utilize o `$int` para aramazenar no banco de dados, e o `$base64` para enviar ao usuário.

Depois, para converter novamente, utilize:

```
$url = 'CODIGO-DO-URL';

$base64 = strtr($url, '-_', '+/');
$base64 = base64_decode($base64);

$int = unpack("J*", $base64)[1];
```

Dessa forma busque no banco de dados o `$int`. Claro, isso pode ter performance pior, afinal existe um custo para conversão. Mas, o espaço de armazenamento necessário será menor, isso é evidente. Mas, acredito que o banco de dados seja um problema maior do que a conversão, ou seja converter o base64 para int ainda tem maiores vantagens.

---