# Como passar Int para Base64 em PHP?

Tags: php, base64

O base64 consegue armazenar 6 bit a cada caractere utilizado. Supondo que estamos usando o int64 ou uint64 nós usamos 64 bits, que poderiam ser representados em ~11 caracteres.

Eu tentei [responder esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266185/php-como-gerar-um-id-%C3%BAnico-igual-o-do-encurtador-do-google), mas o PHP falha em converter os valores corretamente.

```
$int = 5460109885665973483;
echo base64_encode($int);
```

Retorna:

```
NTQ2MDEwOTg4NTY2NTk3MzQ4Mw==
```

Isto é incorreto, estamos usando 26 caracteres para representar 64 bits! Isso é insano. *Eu até entendo o motivo, ele utiliza o valor como string, não como int.* Só que a conversão para string faz usar 19 bytes, que portanto (19*8)/6 caracteres são usados pelo PHP.

Porém, outras linguagens lidam em nível de bytes, como o Golang:

```
bt := make([]byte, 8)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(bt, 5460109885665973483)

fmt.Print(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bt))
```

Retorna:

```
S8Y1Axm4FOs=
```

O `S8Y1Axm4FOs=` é exatamente 11 caracteres (ignorando o padding), que é exatamente a representação dos 64 bits. <sub><sub>Neste caso você consegue recuperar o valor usando o `binary.BigEndian.Uint64` depois do `decode` do Base64.</sub></sub>

---

Qual maneira conseguiria ter o mesmo resultado do Golang no PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso no PHP é utilizando o **[pack](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pack.php)**. Essa função vai permitir ter uma implementação big-endian de ordem de bytes.

```
<?php

$byte_array = pack('J*', 5460109885665973483);    
var_export( base64_encode($byte_array) );

// Output: S8Y1Axm4FOs=
```

Para reverter esse processo, você pode utilizar a função oposta **[unpack](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unpack.php)**

```
<?php

$encoded = "S8Y1Axm4FOs=";

$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);

var_export( unpack("J*", $decoded) );

// Output: [ 1 => 5460109885665973483 ]
```

> O **J*** representa um 64 bit, big endian byte order

Comment: O `pack` sempre salvando. Pela primeira vez vi utilidade nas outras opções do pack, além do `C` e do `H`, vou investigar mais eles. :D

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do [@Valdeir Psr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/266214/15089) responde a pergunta e resolve o problema. Porém, eu tinha uma ideia completamente diferente de resolver a situação, usando bitwise.

Eu pensei em simplesmente dividir o valor a cada 6 bits, então codifica-lo para base64. Isto não seria aprova de ataques side-channel (da mesma forma que o original do PHP), mas seria suficiente para o proposito, creio eu.

Tentei executar essa ideia, e... deu certo. Então, estou compartilhando aqui, embora irei usar o `pack`.

---

Então, basta fazer:

```
function base64_encode_int64(int $int) : string {
    $alfabeto = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
    $base64 = '';

    for($l = 58; $l > 0; $l -= 6){
        $base64 .= $alfabeto[($int >> $l) & 0x3F];
    }
    $base64 .= $alfabeto[($int << 2) & 0x3F];

    return $base64;
}
```

O ultimo shift deve ser *invertido*, porque ele tem apenas 4 bits, são necessários 6. Então é preciso adicionar 2 bits ao fim, por esse motivo o deslocamento "para o lado contrário".

Para decodificar usamos o `|`, que é a solução mais simples, creio eu.

```
function base64_decode_int64(string $base64) {
    $alfabeto = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
    $int = 0;

    if(mb_strlen($base64, '8bit') !== 11){
        return false;
    }

    for($l = 58; $l > -3; $l -= 6){
        $letra = strpos($alfabeto, $base64[(58-$l)/6]);
        if($letra === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if($l > 0){
            $int |= ($letra) << $l;
        }else{
            $int |= ($letra) >> 2;
        }
    }


    return $int;
}
```

Não acredito que o `strpos` seja a melhor opção, além disso a quantidade de `if` está em incomodando um pouco. Isso foi preciso porque a entrada (`$base64`) deve usar o mesmo dicionário, por isso deve retornar `false` em caso de erro, além de ser limitado em 11 caracteres.

O `if($l > 0){` eu trouxe para dentro do `for`, mas não acredito que não seja ideal. Fiz isso para não ter que criar uma nova condição fora do loop (duplicar o `if($letra)`), mas acredito qeu deve haver uma maneira de tornar isso "universal", *talvez fazendo alguns shifts antes (para o lado contrário), não sei*.

---

Agora os testes:

```
echo $int = 5460109885665973483;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $b64 = base64_encode_int64($int);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo base64_decode_int64($b64);
```

Retorna:

```
5460109885665973483
S8Y1Axm4FOs 
5460109885665973483
```

**[Teste isso aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d63fe8e2a1505b8280ace1356ac69fb8ffb9189)**

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz isso, mas não sei se é aceitável... eu usei o método de conversão de binário para hexa/octal aplicando ele para base64 (ou seja, convertendo cada grupo de 6 bits em um caracter correspondente) e para decodificar eu usei a conversão posicional.

Esse método não aplica padding, mas a função b64_decode perfeitamente inverte o efeito de b64_encode, então mesmo que não esteja completamente correto de acordo com os padrões de conversão para base64 (que eu não conheço... eu só expandi o método de conversão para hexadecimal), isso deve servir para economizar espaço e codificar integer de forma confiável (eu espero).

```php
<?php
  function b64_encode(int $number):string {
    $binary = decbin($number);
    $length = strlen($binary);
    $digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    $result = "";

    // Each iteration converts one 6-bit group into one character from the $digits string
    for ($i = $length - 6; $i > -6; $i -= 6) {
      $l = $i >= 0 ? 6 : 6 + $i;
      if ($i < 0) $i = 0;
      $sixBits = substr($binary, $i, $l);
      $result = $digits[bindec($sixBits)] . $result;
    }

    return $result;
  }

  function b64_decode(string $number): int {
    $digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    $length = strlen($number);
    $result = 0;

    for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) $result += strpos($digits, $number[$i]) * 64 ** ($length - 1 - $i);

    return $result;
  }
```