# Biblioteca encryption - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, criptografia

Tenho um problema, estou passando um id via GET e preciso criptografar ele. Então, resolvi usar a biblioteca nativa do codeigniter: encryption, mas quando a mensagem está criptografada, ela gera muitos caracteres, no qual resulta em um problema na passagem pela URL. Tem como diminuir o tamanho da saída da mensagem criptografada?

Codigo para criptografar e decriptografar:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $dados['url'] = base_url();
        $dados['msg'] = '123';
        $dados['msg_cripto'] = $this->encryption->encrypt($dados['msg']);
        $dados['msg_decripto'] = $this->encryption->decrypt($dados['msg_cripto']);
        $this->parser->parse('welcome_message', $dados);
    }
}
```

[image: Resultado retornado.]

Comment: Pra clarear as ideias: por que mesmo que vc precisa criptografar o id na URI?

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem fica maior porque ela utiliza AES-CBC e utiliza o HMAC-SHA512. Isso faz com que o tamanho minimo seja de 16 bytes + 16 bytes + 64 bytes, no total no minimo 96 bytes. Quando codificado para Base64 o "tamanho aumenta".

O AES-CBC trabalha com blocos de 16 bytes, dessa forma o menor bloco possível (mesmo que mensagem seja de 1 byte) será de 16 byte. Se mensagem tiver 17 bytes, o AES irá ter 32 bytes, sempre são blocos de 16.

O HMAC, para garantir integridade da mensagem, usa SHA-512, que sempre terá 64 bytes.

Além disso você tem o IV, que um nonce, ele possui 16 bytes e é um valor público.

---

Qual a "solução" para reduzir o tamanho?

- Encriptação: Não use cifra de blocos.
- Integridade: Não use HMAC.

---

Você pode utilizar o XChaCha20Poly1305. O ChaCha20 é uma cifra de fluxo, portanto o tamanho dele é 1:1. Se a mensagem tiver 1 byte, o dado encriptado também terá 1 byte, sem nada adicional. O Poly1305 é um algorítimo de MAC que utiliza apenas 16 bytes, ao contrário dos 64 bytes, e garante uma melhor segurança, teoricamente.

Existe um "problema" no ChaCha20Poly1305 original, que o nonce é muito pequeno, assim é recomendado que o nonce seja sequencial. Por isso o XChaCha20Poly1305 é usado, para que possa usar nonce aleatório, não tendo que saber o último estado utilizado.

No final você terá no minimo 1 bytes + 24 bytes + 16 bytes, sendo no minimo então 41 bytes, considerando o nonce junto ao texto-crifrado.

Para usa-lo você tem o LibSodium, nativo no PHP 7.2:

```
$nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_XCHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES);
$encriptado = $nonce . sodium_crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt(
    $dados['msg'],
    '',
    $nonce,
    $chave
);
```

Para desencriptar:

```
$desencriptado = sodium_crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt(
    mb_substr($encriptado, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_XCHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, null, '8bit'),
    $ad,
    mb_substr($encriptado, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_XCHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, '8bit'),
    $chave
);
```

> Eu não testei o código postado aqui, então verifique o seu funcionamento e a documentação antes de usa-lo!

Por padrão o LibSodium codifica em hexadecimal, o que é pior do que o Base64, em questão de tamanho, mas você pode decodificar e codificar em Base64.

---

Observe que sua mensagem é uma string númerica, isso irá dar indicios do seu valor através do comprimento do texto. Isso é, se for apenas de 0 até 9 ele ficará com 1 byte, enquanto que se for de 100 até 999 ficará com três bytes... Isso pode ser um problema, já que a pessoa poderá ter grandes chances de adivinhar o valor real através do comprimento.

[Utilize o `pack()` para que sempre utilize 8 bytes, ou 4 bytes em caso de int32, similar ao descrito aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266208/como-passar-int-para-base64-em-php)

---

Agora o problema de "um problema na passagem pela URL", você deve utilizar uma codificação que seja compatível com URL, o PHP, como sempre, não tem recurso nativo para isso. Por padrão o `base64_encode` usa o RFC 2045, não o RFC 3548. O `base64_encode`, padrão, terá caracteres que invalidam o URL, como o `+` e o `=`, por exemplo. Você pode usar o `url_encode`, porém isso irá aumentar ainda mais o tamanho.

Se tamanho for realmente um problema você também pode usar Base91 ou uma codificação personalizada, que seja mais eficiente e ainda segura para utilizar em URLs.